# ¿Cómo saber si existe una etiqueta en una tabla jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

Actualmente extraigo el `id` del producto:

Pero necesito saber si esa fila posee la etiqueta `$('#garantia')` para realizar una acción si la posee.

El `tr id=""` es el mismo que el value del *checkbox* con eso se podría buscar.

Estaba pensando usar `children()` pero desconozco la forma correcta de hacerlo.

```js
$("input:checkbox[name=checkbox_producto]:checked").map(function() {
  return $(this).val()
}).get()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Producto</th>
      <th>valor</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="1">
      <td><input class="check_g" type="checkbox" value="1" name="checkbox_producto"><td/>
      <td>Licuadora</td>
      <td>$40.000</td>
      <td id="garantia">Garantia Extendida</><!-- si activo el checkbox de esta columna necesito saber si posee esta etiqueta-->
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <td><input class="check_g" type="checkbox" value="2" name="checkbox_producto"><td/>
      <td>Lavadora</td>
      <td>$40.000</td><!-- acá la etiqueta no esta por tanto no realizo ninguna acción-->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: corregido gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para saber si tendro de un elemento hay otro en específico, se puede hacer de la siguiente manera:

Supongamos que el id ya lo tienes en la variable 'id'

```
$("#"+id).find("#garantia").length
```

Esto te regresará **> 0** si sí existe la etiqueta.

Comment: justo lo que necesitaba estimado gracias !

Comment: Pues sí, solo se responde lo que el OP pregunta y ya xD Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `children()` en este caso porque los hijos directos de un `tr` son `td`, si tuvieras que buscar en varios niveles de la jerarquia del DOM deberías usar `find()`.

Aunque en HTML puedes usar `id` que empiecen por números en CSS no y jQuery usa selectores CSS para acceder a los elementos así que no deberías usarlos.

Te pongo tu ejemplo usando `children()` y dándole un color de fondo a `td#garantia`, puedes meterlo en una variable y luego realizar la acción que quieras con eso.

```js
$("#fila1").children("#garantia").css("background","yellow");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Producto</th>
      <th>valor</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="fila1">
      <td><input class="check_g" type="checkbox" value="1" name="checkbox_producto"><td/>
      <td>Licuadora</td>
      <td>$40.000</td>
      <td id="garantia">Garantia Extendida</><!-- si activo el checkbox de esta columna necesito saber si posee esta etiqueta-->
    </tr>
    <tr id="fila2">
      <td><input class="check_g" type="checkbox" value="2" name="checkbox_producto"><td/>
      <td>Lavadora</td>
      <td>$40.000</td><!-- acá la etiqueta no esta por tanto no realizo ninguna acción-->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cogiendo como ejemplo la respuesta de @blonfu:

1. Creo que no deberias usar id para identificarlo, porque entiendo que en un futuro la lista podria tener mas en "garantia".
2. He colocado una funcion para que verifique si esta chequeado o no, ya que en la otra respuesta no estaba. De esta manera, si esta chequeado y tiene esa clase es cuando se pondra amarilla.

Esta algo guarro con esos parents, pero me ha parecido la manera mas rapida de mostrarlo.

Con lo que sea dime :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".check_g").change(chekeargarantia);
});

function chekeargarantia(){
if($(this).is(':checked')){
  $(this).parents("tr").children(".garantia").css("background","yellow");
}else{
  $(this).parents("tr").children(".garantia").css("background","transparent");  
}
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Producto</th>
      <th>valor</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="fila1">
      <td><input class="check_g" type="checkbox" value="1" name="checkbox_producto"><td/>
      <td>Licuadora</td>
      <td>$40.000</td>
      <td class="garantia">Garantia Extendida</><!-- si activo el checkbox de esta columna necesito saber si posee esta etiqueta-->
    </tr>
    <tr id="fila2">
      <td><input class="check_g" type="checkbox" value="2" name="checkbox_producto"><td/>
      <td>Lavadora</td>
      <td>$40.000</td><!-- acá la etiqueta no esta por tanto no realizo ninguna acción-->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Si necesita saber si tiene garantía añade algo como if ( $( this ).parent().parent().children( '.garantia' ).length > 0 )

Comment: puedes mejorar lo de los `parent()` con la funcion `parents()` que puede subir varios niveles: `$(this).parents("tr").children(".garantia").css("background","yellow");`

Comment: @JordiHuertas no hace falta, si existe devolverá el objeto y si no existe no

Comment: @blonfu sólo quiere saber si tiene garantía. Es un elemento vacío, sin datos. Está más optimizado si devuelves un número a un objeto, sólo por eso. En caso de que ese td contuviera información del tipo "data-" y se le fuera a dar uso sí que sería más conveniente devolver el objeto.

Comment: @JordiHuertas Ok, quizá si sea más comodo eso y tal vez más rápido (no lo sé), aunque depende de la acción que quiera hacer con ello, si quiere pintar el `td` como en este ejemplo o hacer algo similar no seria necesario

Comment: @blonfu estoy de acuerdo. Solo que lo primero que he pensado (debido a mi curro) es que esa data-table puede estar mostrando 500 registros, y en un pc de la vieja escuela de empresa puede ser una pequeña diferencia de rendimiento.

Comment: @JordiHuertas tienes razon. Pero al igual que los parents, lo que he puesto es para mostrar un código corto y comprensible. Esta claro que hay que optimizarlo, y al igual que tu, con todos los registros que manipulo en el curro, no es como debe estar. Pero creo que para hacerse a la idea, como respuesta esta correcta.

Comment: @blonfu estamos de acuerdo en que estamos de acuerdo, genial. Ahora volvamos al curro ;)

Comment: @JordiHuertas el último comentario no es mío :)

Comment: Genial, quizá haya contestado a mi jefe con otro nombre también.